# Getting data within a certain range from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have a multidimensional array (This data may also contain very large data).

In this data, in a column (example age column) I want to get data in which the data in a column (for example the age column) is within a certain range.

Data;

```
Array(

  1 => array(
     "id" => 1,
     "name" => "John",
     "age" => 18
  ),
  2 => array(
     "id" => 1,
     "name" => "Mike",
     "age" => 19
  ),
  3 => Array (
     "id" => 1,
     "name" => "Weber",
     "age" => 25
  )
  ...
)
```

Imagine data going like this. How can I return the elements of this array with an age range of 18-20? Remember, there may be hundreds of thousands of data. I need to keep the performance as high as possibl
e.

Comment: [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: If this comes from a database query, the best way would be to use a `WHERE` condition in the query. `WHERE age BETWEEN 18 AND 20`. If you need to do this frequently, add an index for the column.

Comment: Barmer, I don't write SQL queries. I'm writing my own NoSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Pippo gave you right answer but not detailed let me help you out with it.

Basically you need to create a function which will return true if current filter is matched, like this:

```
$dataArray = [["id" => 1, "name" => "John", "age" => 18], ["id" => 5, "name" => "Alex", "age" => 12]];
function ageFilter($age){
  // ranging 18-20
  return in_array($age['age'], [18,19,20]);
}
$filteredArray = array_filter($dataArray, "ageFilter");
// print_r($filteredArray) will contain John's data only.
```

Detailed explanation of functions:

- [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: What if I want values ​​greater than 20?

Comment: @XenForq change ageFilter function with return $age['age'] > 20;

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment the best solution should be to use *array_filter()*

A current version of its use can be:

```php
$fullArray = [/* the values*/];
$filterdArray = array_filter($fullArray, fn ($item) => $item['age'] > 20);
```

assuming that you want the values greater than 20.

You can replace the filter condition according to your needs by varying the callable, eg:

```php
// ages between 20 and 50
fn ($item) => $item['age'] >= 20  &&  $item['age'] <= 50
```

```php
// ages equals to 20 or 50
fn ($item) => $item['age'] == 20  ||  $item['age'] == 50
```

for multiple non-contiguous values the best solution is using *array_filter()* as suggested by *nikk.aa*:

```php
fn ($item) => in_array($item['age'], [/* desired values */])
```